# how to get twitter username with twitter4j

Tags: java, android, authentication, twitter

I am developing an app in java in the android studio IDE, the idea is that after logging in with my username and password, I can be redirected to a new view where a user profile is shown with the name, email and profile image. Currently I can log in and after that it redirects to the user profile but I don't know how to get the name, email and profile image.Then I leave you my code in case you have the time to help me, thank you very much for reading:
loggin.class

```
public class loggin extends AppCompatActivity {

    //variable twitter
    Button  twitterButton;
    //TwitterLoginButton login;
    private static final String TAG = "Twitter4j";
    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static final String APIConsumerKey = "xxxx";
    private static final String APIConsumerSecretKey = "xxxx";
    private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "http://myurl"; 
    private static RequestToken twitterRequestToken;
    twitterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initializeTwitter(loggin.this);

            }
        });
}
private static void initializeTwitter(final Activity activity) {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(APIConsumerKey);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(APIConsumerSecretKey);
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                User user;
                try {
                    twitterRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACK_URL);
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", String.valueOf(twitterRequestToken));
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Open Dialog for authentication.
                            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, TwitterAuthActivity.class);
                            if (twitterRequestToken != null) {
                                intent.putExtra("TwitterReqTokenUrl", twitterRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

twitterAuthActivity

```
public class TwitterAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Twitter4j";
    private static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"; //"x-oauthflow-twitter://twitterlogin";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String twitterRequesTokenUrl;
    private WebView twitterWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_twitter);
        twitterWebView = findViewById(R.id.TwitterWebView);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            twitterRequesTokenUrl = extras.getString("TwitterReqTokenUrl");
        }

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        //Setup WebView
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        twitterWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        twitterWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        twitterWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = twitterWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        twitterWebView.loadUrl(twitterRequesTokenUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int[] l = new int[2];
            twitterWebView.getLocationOnScreen(l);
            Rect rect = new Rect(l[0], l[1], l[0] + twitterWebView.getWidth(), l[1] + twitterWebView.getHeight());
            if (!rect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
                finish();
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            boolean response = false;
            if (url.contains(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                //This uri could be saved as access token.
                Log.i(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading() uri " + uri.getPath());
                Intent intent=new Intent(TwitterAuthActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                response = true;
            }
            return response;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Toast.makeText(TwitterAuthActivity.this, "Upps! something happened, retry later!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }



        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(progressDialog.isShowing() && !isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            twitterWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```